# Symfony 3 : Embed Collection of Forms persistence issue : Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'arrivage_id' cannot be null

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-forms, symfony-3.4

I'm working with **Symfony 3.4 lts** and I get an issue with **Embedded Collection Forms** persistance.

This Issue requries a **Symfony Expert** .. The description seems long somewhere but it's 80% of code generated automatically by Symofny CLI default commands.

I'm a reduction expert so You will find that my description is simple and pedagogical,

My 3 entities are described with this simple **UML Diagram Class**

[image]

The code is in french so Arrival is Arrivage, product is Produit and the intermediate entity ArrivalElement is ElementArrivage.

## Entity: Arrivage.php (Arrival in english)

```
/**
 * Arrivage
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="arrivage")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ArrivageRepository")
 */
class Arrivage
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="dateCreation", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateCreation;

    /**
     * @var Arrivage
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ElementArrivage", mappedBy="arrivage", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
     */
    private $elementArrivages;

    public function __construct() {
      $this->dateCreation = new \DateTime();
      $this->elementArrivages = new ArrayCollection();
    }

// bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:Arrivage => OK
```

## Entity: ElementArrivage (intermediate entity created for the Many To Many relation with extra field)

```
/**
 * ElementArrivage
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="element_arrivage")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ElementArrivageRepository")
 */
class ElementArrivage
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var Arrivage
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Arrivage", inversedBy="elementArrivages")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="arrivage_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
     */
     private $arrivage;

     /**
      * @var Produit
      *
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Produit", inversedBy="elementArrivages")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="produit_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
      */
      private $produit;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="quantite", type="integer")
     */
    private $quantite;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="prix_achat", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=3)
     */
    private $prixAchat;

// bin/console doctrine:generate:entities => OK
```

## Entity: Produit.php:

```
/**
 * Produit
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="produit")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProduitRepository")
 */
class Produit
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

     /**
      * @var Arrivage
      * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ElementArrivage", mappedBy="produit", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=TRUE)
      */
     private $elementArrivages;

// bin/console doctrine:generate:entities => OK
```

## Form: ArrivageType.php:

```
class ArrivageType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('elementArrivages', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => ElementArrivageType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'label'=> false,
            'entry_options' => array(
              'label' => false
            )
        ))
        ;

    }/**
```

## Form: ElementArrivage.php:

```
class ElementArrivageType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('quantite')
        ->add('prixAchat')
        ->add('produit', EntityType::class, array(
            // looks for choices from this entity
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Produit',

            // uses the User.username property as the visible option string
            'choice_label' => 'name',

            // used to render a select box, check boxes or radios
            // 'multiple' => true,
            // 'expanded' => true,
        ));
        ;
    }/*
```

So my principal Entity is arrival, I have to create an arrival and it must persist the rest onCascade, So that I have to create a controller only for arrival entity

## ArrivageController:

it still clean after generating crud by doctrine

## View:

I used documentation technique ( prototype ) to allow create new elementArrivage

Doc: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype

Demo javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/847Kf/4/

## **ISSUES:**

With this configuration While Trying to create a new arrival I get a first persistance issue:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO element_arrivage (quantite, prix_achat, prixVente, arrivage_id, produit_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [1, 1, 1, null, 11]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'arrivage_id' cannot be null
```

I resolved this issue by adding a line in Entity Arrivage in the method:

```
public function addElementArrivage(\AppBundle\Entity\ElementArrivage $elementArrivage)
{
    $elementArrivage->setArrivage($this); // Added Liiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiine
    $this->elementArrivages[] = $elementArrivage;

    return $this;
}
```

First Question: Is this a proper Solution ???

After resolving the first issue, I get the second Issue:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO element_arrivage (quantite, prix_achat, prixVente, arrivage_id, produit_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [1, 1, 1, null, 11]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'arrivage_id' cannot be null
```

Second Question: I doesn't have any idea about the solution but When I tried to modify the Controller with this line the problem disappears but it's not a solution because in this case the ElementArrivage will be fixed to two:

## ArrivageController:

```
/**
 * Creates a new arrivage entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="arrivage_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $arrivage = new Arrivage();
    $elementArrivage = new ElementArrivage();   //Added Liiiiines begin
    $elementArrivage2 = new ElementArrivage();
    $arrivage->addElementArrivage($elementArrivage);
    $arrivage->addElementArrivage($elementArrivage2); // Added Liiiines end

    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ArrivageType', $arrivage);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($arrivage);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('arrivage_show', array('id' => $arrivage->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('arrivage/new.html.twig', array(
        'arrivage' => $arrivage,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question on whether manually adding the parent to the child in order for the bi-directional association to be recognized is the right way to do it. Yes it is.

As for your second question. It seems that Doctrine is not able to tell, that it needs to persist the arrivals before it persists the arrival elements, leading to the null id problem you are facing. You might be able to solve this by specifying the `data_class` of your forms like below, to make sure your forms return the correct elements:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => ElementArrivage::class,
    ));
}
```

Even then your entities might not be managed by Doctrine, as you created them manually. Since Symfony Form tries to use the getters and setters of your class, when your Arrivage-class has a setter like this, it should recognize the entities and persist them as well:

```
public function setElementArrivages($elements)
{
    foreach($elements as $element) {
        $this->addElementArrivage($element); // the method from your example
    }
}
```

You might also have to persist without specifying an entity, so just `$em->persist();` instead of `$em->persist($arrivage);` in your controller;

If all this does not work try using xdebug to see if the elements are in the unit of work (uow) of the entity manager. If not, you could always manually persist them:

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $elements = $arrivage->getElementArrivages();
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $em->persist($element);
    }
    $em->persist($arrivage);
    $em->flush();
}
```

When you have to manually have to control Doctrine like this, it usually is a sign that you are doing something that's outside what it wants to do and where it performs well. You might want to look into reorganizing your domain/table mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @dhrumann for your collaboration that was very benefice for me, Now I know that doctrine:generate:crud provides only the primary skeleton of a controller and not a Controller perfectly adapted to my situation.

So, for data_class that was correctly mentioned in my code (automatically generated by doctrine:generate:crud)

Regarding your last code section,I think it isn't logic because you are trying to persist (ElementsArrivage) which contains arrivage_id before persisting the (Arrivage) which is the parent its self. So the arrivage_id will be null and it will causes an issue I think. Do you confirm ?

The Solution I adapt is: (see //Added Block)

## ArrivageController:

```
public function newAction(Request $request){

$arrivage = new Arrivage();

$form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ArrivageType', $arrivage);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    //Added Block Begiiiiiiin
    $elementArrivages = $arrivage->getElementArrivages();
    foreach( $elementArrivages as $elementArrivage){
      $elementArrivage->setArrivage($arrivage);
    }
    //Added Block Ennnnnd

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($arrivage);
    $em->flush();
```